# JComboBox KeyReleased event not working

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, keyevent, keyrelease

I'm using a `JComboBox` to search a query from a sql DB. I want to search query when a letter is typed. I'm using net beans IDE. Here is the automated code.

```
srch.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            srchKeyReleased(evt);
       }
}

private void srchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    //Searching code
}
```

But nothing happens. I'm sue that there is no error in searching code. 
Please give me the code to do this without automated code from IDE.
 name of `JComboBox` is `srch` . Combo box editable=true.
Thank you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your attempt.

Comment: @Hasi007 `I'm sue that there is no error in searching code.` be sure that should be, even `KeyListener` isn't proper `Listener` for `JComboBoxes Editor`, post an `SSCCE` with hardcoded value, short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame`, one `JComboBox` and `hardcoded value stored in local variable`

Comment: @mKorbel How to post an SSCCE? There is no error. IF i use `sout("Done");` instead `searching code`, it doesnt trace "Done" when a keyis typed. I used a `jTextField` and a `JList` instead and used the same code. It works fine.I want to integrate them to a `jComboBox`. Thank you.

Comment: error in coding logics, error in usage of methods implomented in Swing APIs, error by using KeyListener instead of DocumentListener, all these point by default never generating any exceptions, most important thing is EDT issue, I'm never saw searching in Swing and Database without EDT issue, which one is your problem, nobody knows

Comment: @mKorbel anyhow i got the answer from Rempelos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your combobox is editable, you should try this:

```
srch.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener()
```

instead of this

```
srch.addKeyListener()
```

Comment: not, not, wrong, three steps back, for all JTextComponents is there DocumentListener